# Picasso на Androidx

Tags: android, picasso

Всем доброго дня. В связи с тем, что перевожу проект на Androidx, столкнулся с проблемой вывода изображения в ImageView. Стандартное использование библиотеки Picasso. На андроидах версий ниже 8, все работает. На 9 не хочет. Только не хочет отображать изображения с http, а с https прекрасно работает. Гуугление не помогает....

```
Picasso.get()
                .load(Uri.parse("https://intronex.ru/userfiles/news/large/187_modernizatsiya-seti-.jpg"))
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.photo)
                .error(R.drawable.newlogo)
                .into(photoView);
```

Вот эту картинку покажет. А если взять по обычному протоколу http другую картинку, сразу отлуп. Подскажите куда копать.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` в манифест в application. И не обязательно использовать Uri.parse в load. У этого метода есть перегрузка для String, которая делает то же самое

Comment: Uri.parse - это я уже эксперементировал, надеялся, что поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело не в Picasso, а в запрете на `http` протокол в Android API 28+

Работающей схемой является как написано в комментариях добавление в манифест строчки:

```
<application
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Однако данная схема имеет один изьян - она разрешает `http` везде, что по нынешним временам не есть айс, рекомендуемая схема выглядит так.

В теге `application` манифеста надо добавить строчку:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Далее в каталог XML в ресурсах добавить файл `network_security_config` типа такого:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <!-- список доменов которым доверяем-->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">trusted.domain</domain>       
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: да, я это уже понял. ставил другие сторонние библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо Drawn Raccoon! Проблема решена.
добавить android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" в манифест в application.